# Capistrano rand Rubber : Deploy EC2 fails. (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2, capistrano, rubber

I followed this railscast to deploy my Rails application: http://railscasts.com/episodes/347-rubber-and-amazon-ec2?view=asciicast

Something is wrong for me, because after running the command: `cap rubber: create_staging` and follow all the instructions according to the tutorial, my console display the following error after creating the instance:

```
 ** Instance mycustomdomain.com created: i-a53333x1
Waiting for instances to start.......................................................................
 ** Instance running, fetching hostname/ip data
Trying to enable root login
  * 2013-09-28 00:38:48 executing `rubber:_ensure_key_file_present'
  * 2013-09-28 00:38:48 executing `rubber:_allow_root_ssh'
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: '  bash -l -c 'mkdir -p /root/.ssh && cp /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys /root/.ssh/'"
servers: ["xx.xxx.xx.159"]
```

Any ideas or recommendations?

I'm using Mac OS X Mountain Lion.

Thank you.